# Elastisearch - How to process all fields in document while using pipeline processor

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using below processor, but I want to apply it on all fields. So will I need to add all fields in 'field' or is there any other way to do it.

```
   "description": "my pipeline that remvoves empty string and null strings",
   "processors": [
       { 
          "remove": {
              "field": "my_field",
              "ignore_missing": true,
              "if": "ctx.my_field == \"null\" || ctx.my_field == \"\""
          }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `remove` processor doesn't allow you to use wildcard `*` for checking all fields. Instead you can pick the `script` processor and do it yourself in a generic way:

```
  {
    "script": {
      "source": """
          // find all fields that contain an empty string or null
          def remove = ctx.keySet().stream()
                          .filter(field -> ctx[field] == "null" || ctx[field] == "")
                          .collect(Collectors.toList());

          // remove them in one go
          for (field in remove) {
            ctx.remove(field);
          }
          """
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give, comma separate field names, or try with `*`(not sure whether its support, I am trying this), but `comma(,)` separate works for sure, as shown in the official doc

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/remove-processor.html

```
{
  "remove": {
    "field": ["user_agent", "url"]
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to remove all fields without having to specify them all

Comment: @Elasticsearch Ninja  Yes I know we can give comma separated values.But I have many fields in index so I am looking for any other where I need not mention all field names.

Comment: @Val, thanks, yeah as OP mentioned she has many fields, I guess it makes sense to use the script option here

Answer (score 0):

A complete example based on the accepted answer that removes all fields prefixed with `prefix_` from a single document/multiple documents/all documents. Tested using ElasticSearch 6.8.

**Single document:**

```json
POST /<index>/_doc/<id>/_update
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
        def fieldsToDelete = ctx._source.keySet().stream()
            .filter(field -> field.startsWith(params.get("prefix")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        fieldsToDelete.stream()
            .forEach(field -> ctx._source.remove(field));
        """,
    "params": {
      "prefix": "prefix_"
    }
  }
}
```

**Multiple documents:**

```json
POST /<index>/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
  "query": {
    <query-based-on-your-requirements>
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": """
        def fieldsToDelete = ctx._source.keySet().stream()
            .filter(field -> field.startsWith(params.get("prefix")))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        fieldsToDelete.stream()
            .forEach(field -> ctx._source.remove(field));
        """,
    "params": {
      "prefix": "prefix_"
    }
  }
}
```

**All documents:** Same as above, just omit the `query` attribute of the request body.